# Collecting a list of function pointers and other ancillary data via distinct macro invocations

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, compile-time

I want to declare a number of functions with the same signature, possibly spread across different header files, and then use the preprocessor to collect into an array pointers all such functions, and also create an an array of corresponding function names.

So, for example, assuming the common signature is `int func(int x)` I could have the following declarations:

```
FUNC(a) {
  return x + x;
}

FUNC(b) {
  return x >> 1;
}

FUNC(c) {
  return x ^ 123;
}
```

... and the through some macro magic, I would end with something after preprocessing that looks like:

```
int a(int x) {
  return x + x;
}

int b(int x) {
  return x >> 1;
}

int c(int x) {
  return x ^ 123;
}

typedef int (*intfunc_t)(int)

const intfunc_t func_ptrs[] = { &a, &b, &c };

const char *func_names[] = { "a", "b", "c" };
```

A worse version of this is possible using [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), but this requires a list like:

```
#define X_MACRO \
  X(a) \
  X(b) \
  X(c)
```

This duplicates the information already encoded in the `FUNC(a)` definitions and makes it tough use this approach with an unknown number of functions spread across many headers, since this central list always needs to be kept in sync.

So I'm hoping there is some way to have the `FUNC` macro automatically generate the lists.

It doesn't *have* to compile-time constructed arrays as shown, either. Anything that allows me to iterate over the function pointers, and get their name and possibly other ancillary information (added via additional args to `FUNC`) could work, e.g., a linked list initialized at startup. You can assume all the `FUNC` macros appear in the same compilation unit.

While I'm not interested in gcc-specific solutions like `__attribute__((constructor))`.

Comment: This is not possible with the C preprocessor. I would recommend writing a program that you run during the build, which scans your sources for `FUNC(foo)` or some other marker and generates the lists you want.

Comment: Thanks @zwol. I added a clarification at the bottom that it doesn't _have_ to be an array. This opens up the possibility for e.g., of creating a more decentralized linked-list approach. Could that work? E.g., `FUNC` expands to the function and a line which creates a new `Node` object and adds itself to the end of a linked list of all the existing `Node` objects. And then one line at the start to declare `head`...

Comment: it's still not possible, because there is no way to get the name of the _previous_ `Node` object to chain yourself onto.  You were probably imagining that only one list-head declaration needed a name, but that won't work because you can't modify the value of an already-initialized constant object later in the file.

Comment: (I can see a way to make it work if each invocation of FUNC takes both the current and the previous function name, e.g. `FUNC(a,) { ... }  FUNC(b,a) { ... }` ... but that strikes me as _more_ fragile than the x-macro technique you don't like.)

Comment: Yeah, that would be worse (in particular, if I'm just including a bunch of headers which define the functions it wouldn't work since each file would need to know about the others (e.g., the first function in one file would need to refer to the last macro).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to mostly solve your problem.
It is just a minimal adaptation of the x-macros.
But the difference might just make it useable for you:

- The actual functional code stays in distributed headers.
- The core list only needs to be adapted to total number of such functions
  (and their names, if they are not single letter alphabet),
  i.e. it does not mirror the functionality.
- That adapation to number of functions does not require editing the core implementation.

Here is the code, all in one "file", with hints where the files are split.

```
/* content of distributed header a.h */
#define FUNC_a_Implementation()              \
{                                            \
    return x+x;                              \
}


/* content of distributed header b.h */
#define FUNC_b_Implementation()              \
{                                            \
    return x>>1   ;                          \
}


/* content of distributed header c.h */
#define FUNC_c_Implementation()              \
{                                            \
    return ParCode;                          \
}


/* content of core editable header */
/* #include here the headers a.h, b.h c.h
   potentially d.h, e.h and  f.h in the future
 */    

#define MAGIC_LIST(ParFlavor) \
ENTRY_##ParFlavor(a) \
ENTRY_##ParFlavor(b) \
ENTRY_##ParFlavor(c) \

/* add these when needed
ENTRY_##ParFlavor(d)  \
ENTRY_##ParFlavor(e)  \
ENTRY_##ParFlavor(f)  \
*/


/* content of core implementation */
/* include editable core header   */
#define ENTRY_Implementation(ParId) \
int Func##ParId (int x) \
FUNC_##ParId##_Implementation()

#define ENTRY_Pointer(ParId)        \
&Func##ParId,

#define ENTRY_Name(ParId)        \
 "Func"#ParId,

MAGIC_LIST(Implementation)

const intfunc_t func_ptrs[] = {
    MAGIC_LIST(Pointer)
    NULL
}

const char *func_names[] = {
    MAGIC_LIST(Name)
    ""
}
```

When preprocessing this, the result is:

`$MinGW\bin\gcc -E macros.c`

```
# 1 "macros.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "macros.c"
# 50 "macros.c"
int Funca (int x) { return x+x; } int Funcb (int x) { return x>>1 ; } int Funcc (int x) { return x^123; }

const intfunc_t func_ptrs[] = {
 &Funca, &Funcb, &Funcc,
 NULL
}

const char *func_names[] = {
 "Func""a", "Func""b", "Func""c",
 ""
}
```

I added a final entry to the arrays, to avoid their intialisation ending in ",". But I think most compilers will actually allow that.
I expect compilers to replace `"Func""a"` with `"Funca"`. I do not like short identifiers. If your compiler does not do as expected, remove the "Func" everywhere and require the Ids to be long enough.

Expanded macros will never have pretty indentation...

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a header with a function typedef and the prototypes:

```
//the_header.h
typedef int intfunc_t(int);  /*function not function pointer*/
intfunc_t a,b,c; /*prototypes*/
```

include it in each implementation file, and then have one file  with:

```
#include "the_header.h"
const intfunc_t *func_ptrs[] = { a,b,c };
const char *func_names[] = { "a","b","c" };
```

While it is possible to remove the a,b,c duplication  and have something like:

```
//the_header.h
typedef int intfunc_t(int);  /*function not function pointer*/
#define FUNC a,b,c
intfunc_t FUNCS; /*prototypes*/


//collector.c
#include "the_header.h"
const intfunc_t *func_ptrs[] = { FUNCS };
const char *func_names[] = { STRINGIFY_EACH(FUNCS) };
```

Implementing STRINGIFY_EACH would require some dark macro magic (AFAIK), such as:

```
#define STRINGIFY_EACH(...) MC_foreachc(MC_str, __VA_ARGS__)


#define MC_str(_d) MC_str_impl_(_d)                                                          
#define MC_str_impl_(s) #s                                                     
#define MC_foreachc(What, ...) MC_foreachc_(MC_argc(__VA_ARGS__), What, __VA_ARGS__)
    /* MC_foreachc(foo, a,b,c) foo(a), foo(b), foo(c);  */

#define MC_foreachc_0( What, x, ...)  
#define MC_foreachc_1( What, x, ...)  What(x)
#define MC_foreachc_2( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_1( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_3( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_2( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_4( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_3( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_5( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_4( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_6( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_5( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_7( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_6( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_8( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_7( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_9( What, x, ...)  What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_8( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_10( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_9( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_11( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_10( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_12( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_11( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_13( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_12( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_14( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_13( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_15( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_14( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_16( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_15( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_17( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_16( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_18( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_17( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_19( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_18( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_20( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_19( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_21( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_20( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_22( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_21( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_23( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_22( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_24( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_23( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_25( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_24( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_26( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_25( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_27( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_26( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_28( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_27( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_29( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_28( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_30( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_29( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_31( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_30( What, __VA_ARGS__))
#define MC_foreachc_32( What, x, ...) What(x) , MC_expand(MC_foreachc_31( What, __VA_ARGS__))

#define MC_foreachc_(N,  What, ...) MC_expand(MC_cat(MC_foreachc_, N)( What, __VA_ARGS__))
```